# Unit testing/How to assert a non-mocked method was called/C#/Rhino Mocks/NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have a MailService which permit me to send Email which implement the following Interface.

```
public interface IMailService
  {
    bool SendRegisteringEmail(RegisterModel registerModel);
    bool SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage);
    MailMessage CreateRegisteringMailMessage(RegisterModel registerModel);

    IAppSettingsRepository AppSettingsRepository { get; set; }

    ISmtpClient SmtpClient { get; set; }
  }
```

The function SendRegisteringEmail should call CreateRegisteringMailMessage then give the return MailMessage to the SendMail function and SendRegisteringEmail should return the return Boolean of SendMail.

I'm using NUnit and Rhino Mocks to do my test, I'm new to testing (1week) and I'm practicing TDD (At least I try). My problem is I don't know how to assert that CreateRegisteringMailMessage was called when I call SendRegisteringEmail, because MailService isn't a Mocked Object.
Here is my test:

```
[Test]
public void SendRegisteringEmail_ShouldCallCreateRegisteringMailMessage()
{
  //Arrange
  //MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
  IMailService mailService = new MailService { AppSettingsRepository = CreateAppSettingsMockReposotory() };
  //ISmtpClient smtpClientStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISmtpClient>();
  //mailService.SmtpClient = smtpClientStub;
  //smtpClientStub.Stub(f => f.Send(mailMessage)).Return(true);


  //Act
  mailService.SendRegisteringEmail(ValidRegisterModel);

  //Assert
  mailService.AssertWasCalled(f => f.CreateRegisteringMailMessage(ValidRegisterModel));
}
```

I get the following error when I launch my test:
FtpWeb.Tests.MailServiceTests.SendRegisteringEmail_ShouldCallCreateRegisteringMailMessage:
System.InvalidOperationException : The object 'FtpWeb.Models.MailService' is not a mocked object.

I understand why I'm getting this error but now how to test my call.
Since it's the same object I can't mock it to test it.
If anybody can give me some lead to resolve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `CreateRegisteringMailMessage` and `SendMail` seem on a lower abstraction level than `SendRegisteringEmail`. You could consider creating a higher level class containing `SendRegisteringEmail`, and this class would use IMailService, which you could mock and assert as usual.

If the first solution is not an option, then you should treat `SendRegisteringEmail` as a whole, so effectively you have to test the side effects of both `CreateRegisteringMailMessage` and `SendMail` in a single test (a bit of a code smell, hence my suggestion to extract another level of indirection) - see Jon's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you *should* be testing that `CreateRegisteringMailMessage` is called. You should just be checking the *outcome* of calling `SendRegisteringEmail`. What should that do with your `MailService` implementation? Presumably it will have some effect on another service - so test that.

It would be an odd interface design which insisted that calling one method would require another method in the interface to be called - quite often you might make both methods call one private, common method for example.

Comment: I should remove the SendMail method from my interface And put it private? Shoudl I have to do the same with CreateRegisteringMailMessage?
If I do that I will not be able to test it anymore as I have some logic in the last one I need to test.

Comment: @Luuna: I don't know enough about the interface to know... would anyone *publicly* want to call CreateRegisteringMailMessage? That sounds like it shouldn't be part of the public interface to me. Note that it's reasonable (IMO) to test methods which aren't part of the interface - you don't need to refer to the class under test by the interface, you can use the concrete class name.

Answer (score 0):

This is often referred to an 'sensing' within a class under test:  you have to find a way to tell whether a method has been called.  These kinds of things are covered well in the book '[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1282811407&sr=1-1)' which everyone should have (disclaimer: I have no affiliation with the book's author, I just think it's a good book to have).

What does the `CreateRegisteringMailMessage` method do?  Does it affect the content of the `RegisterModel` instance passed in during the call?

Comment: The only book about testing I have is 'The art of unit testing' from Roy Osherove. I have consider buy this one but didn't do it, perhaps I should.
CreateRegisteringMailMessage doesn't modify the content of RegisterModel, it create a MailMessage, fill some information with the RegisterModel and return the MailMessage.

Comment: So can you sense the activity of the CreateRegisteringMailMessage call in the content of the MailMessage?

Comment: @Dr Herbie:Sorry but I don't understand what you are telling me.  
CreateRegisteringMailMessage will be only call by SendRegisteringEmail to create the MailMessage, is that what you asked?

Comment: Yes -- if your test could access the MailMessage could it figure out whether CreateRegisteringMailMessage had been called?  If yes, then consider techniques to expose the sent mail message to the test.